# Sliding window over seq

Tags: clojure, seq, sliding-window

In Clojure, what would be the nicest way to have a sliding window over a (finite, not too large) seq? Should I just use `drop` and `take` and keep track of the current index or is there a nicer way I'm missing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think that [partition](http://clojure.org/api#toc425) with step 1 does it:

```
user=> (partition 3 1 [3 1 4 1 5 9])
((3 1 4) (1 4 1) (4 1 5) (1 5 9))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to operate on the windows, it can also be convenient to do this with map:

```
user=> (def a [3 1 4 1 5 9])
user=> (map (partial apply +) (partition 3 1 a))
(8 6 10 15)
user=> (map + a (next a) (nnext a))
(8 6 10 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know `partition` could do this so I implemented it this way

```
(defn sliding-window [seq length]
  (loop [result ()
         remaining seq]
    (let [chunk (take length remaining)]
      (if (< (count chunk) length)
        (reverse result)
        (recur (cons chunk result) (rest remaining))))))
```